# html td question: hide a td value if another has a value 'not available'

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, html

I have a mysql database with columns `pdf_availability` and `pdf_file`. Below is a part my html table code to view the database using angularjs.

`<td>{{row.pdf_availability}}</td>`

`<td><a href="{{row.pdf_file}}">View</a></td>`

This may sound absurd, but I needed the `<a>` to be hidden in the table (not the entire `<td>`, only the `<a>`) if the `pdf_availability = 'not available'`.

Comment: I'm no angular expert but use [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)? `<a ng-if="row.pdf_availability" href="{{row.pdf_file}}">View</a>` ?

Comment: Why not put an id on both the `td`s and write an extremely simple script?

Comment: The keyword you'll want to google is "conditional rendering". @IslamElshobokshy OP mentions angular in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to every comment, i managed to find the right answer..

adding `ng-hide="row.pdf_availability == 'PDF Not Available'"` works fine..

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs Provide ng-If to check conditions,try this

```
 <a ng-if="pdf_availability != 'not available'" href="{{row.pdf_file}}">View</a>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. i just added this to my code and it doesn't affect the outcome

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides a directive to hide when condition matches criteria

```
<a ng-hide="pdf_availability == 'not available'" href="{{row.pdf_file}}">View</a>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. i just added this to my code and (1) if i use `pdf_availability == 'not available'` it doesn't do anything (2) if use `pdf_availability = 'not available'` it hides every link.